# How I find and active <button class ''... with Python Selenium with Chrome browser

Tags: python-3.x, button, selenium-chromedriver

I have a instagram class button.

```
<button class = "aOOlW   HoLwm "tabindex = "0">Non ora</button>==$0
```

I would like to recognize and enable it.

I try:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_name("Non ora")

element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("aOOlW   HoLwm ")

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[starts-with(@class,"aOOlW. HoLwm")]').click()

elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("aOOlW   HoLwm ")
elem.click()
```

This is one of the errors I have:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".aOOlW   HoLwm "}
```

(Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despite a lot of faults in implementations:

try this one:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'aOOlW') and contains(@class, 'HoLwm')]").click()
```

also, you may to consider awaiting for element to be clickable:

```
elem_path = "//button[contains(@class, 'aOOlW') and contains(@class, 'HoLwm')]"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, elem_path)))
```

Comment: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'aOOlW') and contains(@class, 'HoLwm')]").click()     IT'S OK!!! Thank a lot!!!